# Android Studio format theme error

Tags: java, android-studio

I really need help about this error [the 'Theme' is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh0HP.png)

Comment: Add your code and error messages here instead of a picture, so we can copy/paste it to modify and so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a **"Clean Project"** should fix errors like this.

To clean your Android project, in the toolbar on top, go to Build->Clean Project

If that doesn't work, then try **"Invalidate Cache/Restart"**

To do that, in the toolbar on top, go to File->Invalidate Cache/Restart

Comment: Not a problem, if your issue was solved by the answer, you can accept the answer and close the question :-) @jakiejones